# Is there a way to define text within a div as plain text in pug?

Tags: html, pug, pug-loader

I'm not that experienced in using pug and I'm trying to find a way to ignore specific parts of my text as it is presenting errors when compiling. Below is an example of what I am trying to ignore.

```
        +CodeBreak
            >> stuff.clean!
            => ["put away", "put away", "put away"]
```

I am trying to make pug read this specific part as plaintext so it doesn't throw any errors when I am compiling.

```
            >> stuff.clean!
            => ["put away", "put away", "put away"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pug's [block in a tag](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) syntax for multiline plain text. Add a period immediately after the parent element (or mixin):

```
+CodeBreak.
  >> stuff.clean!
  => ["put away", "put away", "put away"]
```